# Excel VBA - Index/Match Change Array/Range each time through loop

Tags: excel, vba

First off my apologies if this has been previously answered but I've been looking for about a day and couldn't find anything.

Part of my macro will compare two columns (A and B) to get understand what has changed from one month to the next.

First I will look at what is in A and not in B to determine what was added.

```
i = 3
For Each rngCell In Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A200")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Data").Range("B2:B200"), rngCell) = 0 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
    End If
i = i + 1
Next
```

I will then look at what is in B and not in A to determine what was removed.

```
n = 3
For Each rngCell In Sheets("Data").Range("B2:B200")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A200"), rngCell) = 0 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
    End If
n = n + 1
Next
```

This works for me.  I then want to compare more columns (eg. C and D, E and F, G and H.....etc).  I would like to create a For Loop so I don't have to right these two set of instructions another 30 or more times.

I'm stuck on how to pass a variable into the Range so that instead of A2:A200 I have something like Range(Cells(Integer, 2), Cells(Integer, 200)).

I'd appreciate help if someone has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub procedure and pass the `leftRange` and `rightRange` as arguments:

```
Public Sub DoStuff(ByRef leftRange As Range, ByRef rightRange As Range, ByRef summaryCells As Worksheet)
  For Each rngCell In leftRange
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rightRange, rngCell) = 0 Then
        summaryCells.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Then you just call it like:

```
Public Sub test()
  ' A against B
  Call DoStuff(Sheets("Internal_Data").Range("A2:A200"), Sheets("Internal_Data").Range("B2:B200"), Sheets("SummaryCells"))

  ' B against A
  Call DoStuff(Sheets("Internal_Data").Range("B2:B200"), Sheets("Internal_Data").Range("A2:A200"), Sheets("SummaryCells"))



  ' do it with a loop
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Set ws = Sheets("Internal_Data")
  Dim col As Long

  For col = 1 To 4 Step 2
    Call DoStuff(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, col), ws.Cells(200, col)), ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, col + 1), ws.Cells(200, col + 1)), Sheets("SummaryCells"))
    Call DoStuff(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, col + 1), ws.Cells(200, col + 1)), ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, col), ws.Cells(200, col)), Sheets("SummaryCells"))
  Next
End Sub
```

Untested, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you for the response Joseph.  I will try this out later today or tomorrow.

Comment: I'm still playing around with this but haven't got it right yet.  It only grabs the first two columns that I'm comparing and it dumps all of the uniques into the same column in the secondary worksheet.

Comment: Ok.  I modified it slightly so that it grabs all the data I want.  The only issue still there is that it puts everything in the same output column in the Summary sheet.  My goal is for the first time through the loop the "New" items get copied to column A in the Summary sheet and the "Removed" items get copied to column D.  The second time through the loop I'd have A+6 (G) and D+6 (J) and so on.